# Why does my double lose its value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, floating-point, double

```
- (void)useX:(double)x {
    self.XVelocity = x;
    //This is called by the app delegate every 1/60 times a second
    printf("%f",x);
}
```

In a different method I use

```
- (void)update {
    printf("%f",self.XVelocity);
}
```

and self.XVelocity is equal to 0, how can I fix this

Comment: Without seeing some complete example code, this is pretty difficult to answer.

Comment: Please post the property and ivar declaration of XVelocity.

Comment: @property (nonatomic) double XVelocity; and double XVelocity;

Comment: My guess is that you're referring to two different instances of your containing object.

Comment: (And you do have the property @synthesized, right?)

Comment: yes I am and their is nothing else called XVelocity I just checked

Comment: Search "XVelocity" to see if they appear at left hand side of assignment. Do you accidentally reset it or on purpose somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "self." and see what will happen.